# How to write a java object to a jobject array in JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I want my native function to take the java object as parameter and write it to jobject array in shared memory for the use of another process. How can I do this ? Thanks.

Comment: lets say I somehow have an access to array in shared memory. So I wonder how to take java object and write it to array ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot share a Java object across processes. The object lives in a VM and two processes have separate VMs. (Or your second process might not have a VM at all.)

You will have to extract all instances variables / properties from the Java object, put them in a *struct* (or a similar data structure) and share the *struct*.